# Is there a way to configure Doxygen such that references between packages also become visible?

Tags: doxygen

*If you come across this question:  This issue is related to Doxygen 1.9.8, previous (and later) versions are okay.*

In Doxygen references can be show between functions. This appears in the html or xml file as `References` and `ReferencedBy`
For example:
[Doxygen html show references snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Yh0.png)

This works perfectly fine when classes are in the same package. However when classes are in different packages these references are missing.

For example given below Java code a reference to A.A1.a() (same package) is shown in the html but a reference to B.B1.b (different package) was also expected:

```
package A;

import B.B1;

/**
 *
 */
public class M {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A1.a();
        B1.b();
    }

}
```

The Doxygen configuration is as follows:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
```

Doxygen version used: 1.9.8

Is there a way to configure Doxygen such that references between packages also become visible?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Are the other packages handled in the same run of doxygen or in different runs? In the later case did you have a look at the tag file possibilities? Can you give a small example that shows all relevant information (other functions i.e. `a`, `b` etc.)? You might also need `EXTRACT_STATIC=YES`.

Comment: The doxygen version is 1.9.8

Comment: All files are handled in one run. I tried EXTRACT_STATIC but no that made no difference.
Sources and configuration can be found  here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vmbLaaE_M8RFnvoJplymJQQQ0rWt1lTW?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like tht the import for Java is not handled properly, I can see there is some, recent, support for import but this is geared towards modules in cpp. Probably best to file a bug report in the doxygen ussue tracer on GitHub.

Comment: I'm looking a bit deeper into the matter and it looks like the 1.9.7 version of doxygen works (would fit with my earlier observations regarding the cpp modules).

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 10385, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10385)

Comment: Reverted to 1.9.7 and that indeed fixes the issue.
I will also try your patch tomorrow.

Comment: Tried https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10385 and it also solves the issue. Thanks for the fast help

Comment: Code of proposed patch, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10385, has been integrated in master on GitHub